# How deep does "finally" go?

Tags: python, function, error-handling, scope, try-catch

Suppose I had the python function :

```
def someFunction(file):
    try:
        for i in file:
            i+=1
    except: 
        showWarning()
    finally:
        file.close()
```

And this function was called inside of another function like so:

```
def otherFunction(thing):
    if thing:
         someFunction(thing)
```

Then I went on to write a for loop such that

```
for i in range(num):
    try: 
        otherFunction(input)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        continue
```

In this specific case would the `finally` of the function `someFunction` be called if the keyboard interrupt happens in this for loop or would the function terminate immediately and the try/except in the for loop take over.

In other words, if I am trying to catch a keyboard interrupt, is it better to put it in the first function where the file close is or is it better to do it in the for loop?

Comment: You have two `for` loops in your code.  Please clarify what you mean by "the" `for` loop.

Comment: I meant the for-loop with the keyboard interrupt exception

Comment: If a keyboard interrupt just so happens while the code is in the `try:` block of  `someFunction`, then it will be caught by the bare `except:` (which is bad Python style, BTW), `showWarning()` will be called, and the file will be closed. Otherwise, if a keyboard interrupt happens anywhere else (say, right before `if thing:` in `otherFunction()`, then the exception will bubble up the stack and be caught by `except KeyboardInterrupt()`.

Comment: @Tom: Please be more specific about where the hypothetical exception is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Among many other things providing a detailed description of how `try/except/finally` works, [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) says:

> the finally clause always executes

If an exception happens inside the `try` block that is inside `someFunction`, then the `finally` clause of that block will execute.  No code higher up in the call stack (i.e., code in functions that called `someFunction`) can change that.

If the exception doesn't happen inside the `try` block (or inside code called from inside the `try` block), then the `finally` clause won't execute.  It's not clear to me from your question where the hypothetical KeyboardInterrupt is supposed to occur.  If it occurs, for instance, on the line that says `for i in file`, then the `finally` in `someFunction` will execute.  If it occurs on the line that says `otherFunction(input)` (before `otherFunction` is actually called), then the `finally` in `someFunction` won't execute, because `someFunction` hasn't yet been called at that time.

Comment: Will all finals always execute ?

Comment: @Tom: If a `try` executes, its `finally` block will always execute, yes.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    something
except:
    something
finally:
    something
```

bounds together on the same level, regardless of what is outside, or inside.

So if your execution went inside the `try` in the  `someFunction(file)`, the `finally` will be executed "no matter what happens"

Should you be calling some other functions inside this block and exception would happen while in the call, the `finally` would be executed.

If exception happens before the execution reach this `try` or after the `finally` is done, then this `try .. except ... finally` block is out of play and does not do anything funny